# Failing changing hexo-theme-next6.6.0 hyperlink style

Tags: hexo

I tried to use all the methods that the search engine can search for modifying the hyperlink style of the theme but they didn't take effect.

The method I have tried：
https://vonsdite.cn/posts/13afd8d4.html

https://neveryu.github.io/2016/09/30/hexo-next-two/

https://blog.junyu.io/posts/0010-hexo-learn-from-Never-yu.html#hyperlink

I have tried to write the following code to this file.
`themes\next\source\css\_custom\custom.styl`

```
.post-body p a {
color: #0593d3;
border-bottom: none;
&:hover {
color: #0477ab;
text-decoration: underline;
}
}
```

After writing the above code, I tried to update the webpage using the hexo cl && hexo g && hexo d command, but the hyperlink style has not changed.

Comment: This is the website that i want to change 
  https://www.52debug.cn/posts/5c6193c6.html#more                                                 
 The hyperlink style at the bottom of the article has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by myself!
The  reason that the CSS didn't work is that i had enabled external URL with BASE64 encrypt & decrypt,and this conflicts with that CSS style!